# SQL view design display blank window

Tags: sql-server, view, ssms

I'm focusing on a Data Warehouse. I'm creating view's for OLAP Cubes.
My problem is some view's don't respond after create. For example I've created a view with product information and based on it I created some other views for sales, purchases etc. In this way I recognized that I need to expand a bit my product view. Now opening it ends with a blank page where I see only randomly refreshing cursor icon, or even if I get in trying to save end with timeouts.
The one thing I figured after I rename this view it works faster but it don't always lets me rename it (timeouts). Is there any solution? Can it be because of low free space in database?

Comment: Which dbms, which tool, what "page"?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 18, with page I mean when I use 'edit design' on a view it open up a new 'page' but it  has 0 content. Normally it would be design editor or anything but for me it's blank nothing that I can do there.